# CheckBox Image as a column in jqxGrid

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqxgrid

I am using jqxGrid plugin to display the data in a Grid. I have 4 columns in which one of them is a CheckBox image column...

This is my column settings for the checkbox Image

```
        columns: [ // Column names
                  {text: '', datafield: 'Check', editable: false, width: colWidth * 0.3, cellsrenderer:   function(row, column, value) {
                     return '<span style="margin:4px;float:left"           
                                  onclick="clickImage(this)"><img class="image-unchecked" 
                                          src="../../Images/checkbox_off.png"/></span>'
}, renderer: function(value) {
                    return '<span style="margin:4px;float:left" onclick="clickImage(this)">
                      <img class="image-unchecked" src="../../Images/checkbox_off.png"/></span>'}
]
```

In the clickImage function I am replacing the source based on the clase name. If on shown check mark image else show empty image.
This click event seems to fire when the cell is clicked ..  But when the cloumnHeader is clicked the click event is not being fired for some unknown reason.. Can some one help me with it..

I have also tried the 'columnclick' which is not working... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$("#jqxgrid").bind('columnclick', function (event) {
    var column = event.args.datafield;
    alert(column);
}
```

See:
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/#demos/jqxgrid/customrowsselection.htm